# Export all opened chrome tabs from android phone to desktop/laptop

Tags: applications, sync, chrome-for-android, google

I have a lot of chrome tabs opened (both individually as well as in groups) in my Android phone. I am having a lot of problems in accessing them and navigating between them all one by one in my Android phone. I want to export all of them to my desktop or laptop as I think I will be able to better manage my tabs using a computer. However, I was not logged into my Google account in Android chrome till now so none of the tabs in my Android phone are synced with my Google account. Also, I don't think that logging at this moment with my Google account in Android chrome will sync them all with my Google account. How do I get all my open Android chrome tabs exported to my lappy or PC?